# What's the vice versa of "they go low, we go high?"

Tags: negation, metaphors, logic

The expression "vice versa" seems to have been used to express something opposite, but there are a bunch of "opposite" things.

My question is when one writes or says

> When they go low [`TL`], we go high [`WH`]. And vice versa,

what do the readers and listeners think?

1. when we go high, they go low (when `WH`, then `TL`; `WH` => `TL`)
2. when they go high, we go low (opposite of `TL`  =>  opposite of `WH`)
3. when they don't go low, we don't go high (not `TL`  =>  not `WH`)
4. etc.

Comment: You can't sensibly say "vice versa" with the aphorism "when they go low, we go high." The phrase **vice versa** means that the two things are interchangeable or equivalent. But when we go high and they go low, the two groups are doing *opposite* things, so they can't be interchanged or said to be equivalent.

Comment: Vice versa refers to the converse of a statement, i.e of an implication.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I haven't gotten your point yet. Do average folks think/feel/judge it's strange, meaningless, stupid or funny as a result?

Comment: @AlexD Is that "1. when we go high, they go low?" this one is what I personally thought.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Or vague?

Comment: I *may* be mistaken, but I think it's incredibly unlikely Clinton would have wanted anyone to assume an implicit ***...and vice versa*** when coming out with this little dictum. In context, what she meant was *If our political opponents descend to smear tactics, we will respond by claiming the moral high ground* - which is a perfectly acceptable position to take when campaigning. The corollary *If they claim the moral high ground we will respond with smear tactics* is NOT a publicly acceptable campaign strategy. Perhaps that's partly why Clinton lost (because people *did* pick up on that! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way the statements are written means that TL is necessary and sufficient condition for WH.

I don't include much detail in my answer, because it delves into formal logic, which is not the subject of this stack; however, I could expand my answer if you would like me to.

It is worth noting that logic does not correspond to casual language at a semantic level.

Comment: You mean (TL => WH) & (WH => TL) in classical logic?

Answer (score 1):

In this context:

> We react to what they do. We can't change what they do. And we are assuming that they are going to take some action.

So the "vice versa" here would generally be interpreted as:

> When they go low, we go high.
>
> And when they go high, we go low.